# AutoDeploy Jenkins, Payara

Tags: jenkins, payara, autodeploy

I want an automated deploy to payara server with Jenkins, but I don't know how to achieve this. Could someone please help me?

Maybe I should use docker or any other application to make this job. I used the plugin "deploy war/ear" but this was the error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\pp1>exit 0 
Deploying C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\pp1\target\despliegue1-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war to container GlassFish 3.x Remote with context 
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.glassfish.api.admin.InvalidCommandException: V3 cannot process this command at this time, please wait
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteAdminCommand.fetchCommandModel(RemoteAdminCommand.java:1152)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteAdminCommand.getCommandModel(RemoteAdminCommand.java:330)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.remote.RemoteCommand.prepare(RemoteCommand.java:297)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:242)
    at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.remote.RemoteCommand.executeAndReturnOutput(RemoteCommand.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.client.RemoteDeploymentFacility$RemoteCommandRunner.run(RemoteDeploymentFacility.java:117)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException
    at org.glassfish.deployment.client.RemoteDeploymentFacility$RemoteCommandRunner.run(RemoteDeploymentFacility.java:121)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.client.AbstractDeploymentFacility.listReferencedTargets(AbstractDeploymentFacility.java:704)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: error submitting remote command
    at org.glassfish.deployment.client.AbstractDeploymentFacility.listReferencedTargets(AbstractDeploymentFacility.java:735)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.client.AbstractDeploymentFacility.listTargets(AbstractDeploymentFacility.java:693)
    at org.glassfish.deployapi.SunDeploymentManager.getTargets(SunDeploymentManager.java:169)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalStateException: error submitting remote command
    at org.glassfish.deployapi.SunDeploymentManager.getTargets(SunDeploymentManager.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.findTargetModule(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:439)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.spi.deployer.AbstractJsr88Deployer.redeploy(AbstractJsr88Deployer.java:197)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1077)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1060)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1840)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O Steven. As I can see, you are try to deploy a java application to glasfish in payara using jenkins. Is it correct? Also in your log I can see windows paths. Is this a proof of concept?

Comment: no these is the error in console of jenkins, in real, i want deploy a java aplication in  payara using jenkins, i downloaded the plugin "Deploy war/ear" but in the moment of configurate my item jenkins only have suport to glassfish 3.1. there is any form that deploy my aplication in payara with jenkins?

Comment: Do you have any screenshot?

Comment: In real environment, your Jenkins is installed in windows?

Comment: the log console is up of my ask

Comment: Almost every server has a deploy engine. Did you try **asadmin** tool for payara?